# Spearman correlation p-values in Perl

Tags: r, perl, correlation

I am looking for a way to calculate Spearman rank correlation coefficients and two-tailed p-values. I found a module [Statistics::RankCorrelation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::RankCorrelation) that does former.

For calculation of p-values I tried to use formula for getting [t-statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Determining_significance):

```
t = r * sqrt( n - 2 / 1 - r^2 )
```

I have tried to calculate p-values based on t-statistic:

```perl
use Modern::Perl;
use Statistics::RankCorrelation;
use Statistics::Distributions;

my $weight = [ 3430, 2920, 3285, 2690, 3260, 3877, 2835, 1440, 2030 ];
my $age    = [ 38.5, 38.3, 40.9, 37.3, 40.3, 42.4, 40.1, 29.3, 36.0 ];

my $cor_var = Statistics::RankCorrelation->new( $weight, $age, sorted => 1 );
my $df = $cor_var->{'size'} - 2; # Degrees of freedom
my $rho = $cor_var->spearman;    # Correlation Coefficient rho

my $tstat = $rho * sqrt( $df / ( 1 - $rho**2 ) ); #T-statistic

# Calculation of two tailed p-value as t-distribution is symmetric:
my $tprob_two_tailed = 2 * Statistics::Distributions::tprob ($df,$tstat);
print $tprob_two_tailed;
```

The problem is that the printed p-value `0.0024954` differs from the one I got in R with cor.test and I don't know where I have made a mistake:

```
weight = c(3430, 2920, 3285, 2690, 3260, 3877, 2835, 1440, 2030)
age = c(38.5, 38.3, 40.9, 37.3, 40.3, 42.4, 40.1, 29.3, 36.0)
cor.test(weight, age, method = "spearman")

    Spearman's rank correlation rho

data:  weight and age
S = 16, p-value = 0.004508
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
      rho 
0.8666667
```

Comment: Can you use the function `spearman` in [Statistics::RankCorrelation](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/GENE/Statistics-RankCorrelation-0.1205/lib/Statistics/RankCorrelation.pm)? Here are some modules that could be useful: [Word2vec::Spearmans](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/CUFFYCA/Word2vec-Interface-0.039/lib/Word2vec/Spearmans.pm), [Math::GSL::Statistics](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/LETO/Math-GSL-0.40/pod/Statistics.pod), [UMLS::Similarity](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/HENRYST/UMLS-Similarity-1.49/utils/spearmans.pl)

Comment: For more results, see [grep.cpanauthors](https://grep.cpanauthors.org/search?q=spearman)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Håkon! I was able to use function spearman in Statistics::RankCorrelation and got rho coefficient. Now I am looking for a way to calculate rank correlation two-tailed p-value.  I will check other modules as you mentioned.